# Legend of World Reference Base (2006) Soil Group

Tags: legend, mapping, wcs, soil, soilgrids

How Can I get the legend for the downloaded WRB soil groups whether from the https://soilgrids.org/ website or directly downloaded from WCS server https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/wrb.map into QGIS?

The legend is shown in numbers. Is it the World Resource Base (WRB) group number for the most probable Soil Group?

if it is, what is the specific number of each soil group?

Comment: Please add a screenshot and possibly a mock-up of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

The WCS standard does not have a request to return a legend, that only makes sense with a WMS. For that service you can use the `GetLegendGraphic` request. Here is an example for that service:

```
https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/wrb.map&
REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&
VERSION=1.3.0&
FORMAT=image/png&
SLD_VERSION=1.1.0&
WIDTH=100&HEIGHT=250&
LAYER=MostProbable&
SERVICE=WMS&
STYLE=default
```

Answer (score 1):

For a higher quality legend you can choose the SVG format, having the following request:

```
https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/wrb.map&
REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&
VERSION=1.3.0&
FORMAT=image/svg%2Bxml&
SLD_VERSION=1.1.0&
LAYER=MostProbable&
SERVICE=WMS&
STYLE=default
```